# The precise definition of Cartesian coordinate and Euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'd searched them for a while, but still have not found a clear and unity definition on it. The problem really confused me.

What is the precise **definition** of Cartesian coordinate and Euclidean space?

Is the definition of Cartesian coordinate including some non-abstract(in a geometric manner?) notion, such like *axes*, *origin* and *the specify of direction*? Or it is just a purely **set**, such like $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$, possibly with the operations defines on it?

The same questions comes to the definition of Euclidean spaces. What does it mean? Does it include some non-abstract(in a geometric manner?) notion, such like *axes*, *origin* and *the specify of direction*? Is it different to Cartesian space? Or, is any vectors space $V$ over any field(including $\mathbb{C}$) that has an inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$ defines on it can altogether be called a Euclidean space?

And the last of all, what is a real coordinate system?

Comment: Concerning the definition of Euclidean spaces: An Euclidean space is a normed vector space where the norm is the Euclidean norm. The Euclidean norm is the so called 2-norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|_2:=\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$.

Comment: Concerning the definition of Cartesian coordinate systems I am not completely sure. But in my experience, coordinate systems that are orthogonal are called Cartesian (in contrast to other systems such as polar coordinate systems).

Comment: The term "real" in "real coordinate system" means that all coordinates are real numbers.